# Test to validate ruby subclasses implement strategy method

Tags: ruby, validation, rspec, subclass, strategy-pattern

I'm implementing a simple strategy pattern (for the first time in ruby) and I want to write a test to make sure that every subclass implements the crucial strategy method. So, I have something like this:

```
class SearchTools::MusicSearcher
  def find_artists
    raise 'Abstract method called'
  end
end

class SearchTools::LastFMSearcher < MusicSearcher
  def find_artists(search_phrase)
    # get artists from lastfm's restful api
  end
end

class SearchTools::DatabaseSearcher < MusicSearcher
  def find_artists(search_phrase)
    # look in database for artists
  end
end

class SearchTools::Search

  def initialize(searcher)
    @searcher = searcher
  end

  def find_artists(search_phrase)
    @searcher.find_artists(search_phrase)
  end

end
```

I'm currently using rspec, factory_girl and shoulda-matchers for my testing. Anyone know how I achieve this?

Cheers!

P.S. I'm used to specifying a literal 'interface' with C#, so that's why I'm looking to see what I can use in ruby to enforce a common interface for each strategy...

Comment: Thanks for the response Dave. respond_to looks good... but how to apply that test to any subclass of my abstract MusicSearcher?

Comment: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2992

Comment: (Although I may not be understanding what you're asking--are you saying you don't want to specifically test the subclasses (which seems weird, since you'd have to test them anyway), or...?)

Comment: Hi Dave - that link looks good but I'm having trouble implementing the self.subclasses method on my own class. I do want to test every subclass of the parent MusicSearcher... hopefully automatically. So when someone creates a new subclass and runs the specs, I'd like to check that their subclass implements the correct interface methods...

Comment: I'm trying to do this:

class SearchTools::MusicSearcher
  def find_artists(search_engine)
    raise 'Abstract method called.'
  end
  
  def self.subclasses
    classes = []
    ObjectSpace.each_object(Class) do |c|
      next unless c.superclass == self
      classes << c
    end
  end
end

and in the test:

describe SearchTools::MusicSearcher do
  describe 'all first-level subclasses' do
    searcher = SearchTools::MusicSearcher.new
    searcher.subclasses.each |subclass| do
      subclass.should respond_to(:find_artists)
    end
  end
end

Comment: But if their class doesn't implement the right method(s) won't the specs fail? I mean, how are subclass implementors getting their code to run with your specs to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect it to be something like,

```
it "should respond to find_artists method" do
  o = SearchTools::LastFMSearcher.new
  o.respond_to?(:find_artists).should be_true
end
```